# How to add labels in geopandas geoplot?

Tags: python, geopandas, geoplot

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
```

What I want to achieve is to plot the data with labels, for instance, to add corresponding values of columns `iso_a3` and `pop_est` as labels on each geometry on the plot.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lambda function to plot the labels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
world.plot(ax=ax)
world.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['iso_a3'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'), axis=1)
```

In this case the labels are plotted in the center of each polygon. In case you want to plot more labels you case use the centroid plus a small offset.